# Rails- in place editing using best_in_place gem for an array collection defined in model itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, inplace-editing, best-in-place

I have seen [RailsCasts#302](http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing) which describes about the in-place editing using the best_in_place gem. Over there in for gender option Ryan uses the array inside the show.html.erb and makes it a dropdown box(see the gender section where he explicitly defines an array).

```
<p>
  <b>Gender:</b>
  <%= best_in_place @user, :gender, type: :select, collection: [["Male", "Male"], ["Female", "Female"], ["", "Unspecified"]] %>
</p>
```

But what I want is I have defined an array inside the Model itself like: (because my array elements are not simple and short in count)

For eg:

*user.rb*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def authencity_types
    ['Asian', 'Latin-Hispanic', 'Caucasian']
  end
end
```

How am I going to use this array elements as dropdown using the `best_in_place` syntax.

PS: I did try something like this

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= best_in_place user, :authencity, type: :select, :collection => User::authencity_types  %>
<% end %>
```

But it says undefined method authencity_types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're defining an instance method on the User model, so try this.

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= best_in_place user, :authencity, type: :select, :collection => user.authencity_types  %>
<% end %>
```

Alternatively you can define that as a class method like this.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.authencity_types
    ['Asian', 'Latin-Hispanic', 'Caucasian']
  end
end
```

Or you may want to consider using a constant if it does not need to be dynamic.

Comment: That worked! thanks a lot Ryan! :) I knew there was very small basic thing bugging me ..but confused.

Comment: For some reason it shows up only the second char or each array so I made my array as array of arrays & it worked. `[['Asian','Asian'], ['Latin-Hispanic','Latin-Hispanic'], ['Caucasian','Caucasian']]`